# SelfMutate stage failing with CodePipeline

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create a CI/CD using CDK pipeline with the import `software.amazon.awscdk.pipelines.CodePipeline` in Java.
This pipeline creates another stack named **xxxJavaxxxStack**.
The pipeline is able to connect to external github, which, when change is detected, triggers the pipeline.

In the class `xxxPipelinexxxApp.java` I'm calling both the stacks `xxxJavaxxxStack` and `xxxPipelinexxxStack`. I have successfully been able to **cdk synth** both separately and **cdk deploy** them separately.

This creates 2 different cloudformation templates, it also creates the pipeline and the first 2 stages go through.
However, the pipeline is failing at **SelfMutate** stage.

The pipeline stages are:

- **Source** - Success
- **Build** - Success

  - **Synth** - Success
- **SelfMutate** - Failed

The error:

```
Error: No stacks match the name(s) xxxPipelinexxxStack

at CdkToolkit.validateStacksSelected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:545:13)
    at CdkToolkit.selectStacksForDeploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:492:10)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:120:20)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)

Command did not exit successfully cdk -a . deploy xxxPipelinexxxStack --require-approval=never --verbose exit status 1
Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cdk -a . deploy xxxPipelinexxxStack --require-approval=never --verbose. Reason: exit status 1
```

Command: `sudo cdk bootstrap`
Result:

```
@aws-cdk/core:newStyleStackSynthesis' context set, using new-style bootstrapping  ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://xxxxxx729/us-east-1... Trusted accounts for deployment: xxxxxx729 Trusted accounts for lookup: (none) Execution policies: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess  Environment aws://xxxxxx729/us-east-1 bootstrapped (no changes).
```

App Code -

```
public class xxxxPipelinexxxApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        final xxxJavaxxxStack javaStack = new xxxJavaxxxStack(
            app,
            "xxxJavaxxxStack",
            StackProps.builder()
                .env(
                    new Environment.Builder()
                        .account("xxxxxx5729")
                        .region("us-east-1")
                        .build()
                )
                .build()
        );
        final xxxPipelinexxxStack pipelineStack = new xxxPipelinexxxStack(
                app,
                "xxxPipelinexxxStack",
                StackProps.builder()
                    .env(
                        new Environment.Builder()
                            .account("xxxxxx5729")
                            .region("us-east-1")
                            .build()
                    )
                    .build()
        );
        app.synth();
    }
}
```

Stack code -

```
public class xxxPipelinexxxStack extends Stack {
    public xxxPipelinexxxStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public xxxPipelinexxxStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        CodePipeline pipeline = CodePipeline.Builder
                .create(this, "pipeline")
                .pipelineName("xxxPipelineXXX")
                .synth(
                        ShellStep.Builder.create("Synth")
                            .input(
                                    CodePipelineSource.connection("<git-owner>/<git-repo>", "main",
                                        ConnectionSourceOptions.builder().connectionArn("<git-repo-connection-arn>").build()
                                    )
                            )
                            .commands(
                                    Arrays.asList("mvn clean install", "npx cdk synth")
                            ).build()
                ).build();
        final xxxPipelineXXXStage deploy = new xxxPipelineXXXStage(this, "Deploy");
        pipeline.addStage(deploy);
    }
}
```

P.S: I'm using a different IAM user, to deploy, than the root user as apparently there are issues when trying to deploy the pipeline using root user.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't deploy the app stack manually, the pipeline should be the one to do it. Best to destroy the one you deployed yourself. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Can you share some code of the pipeline? Are you specifying the environment for the pipeline stack (account/region)?

Comment: Thanks for your response @gshpychka. Yes, I've tried all possible ways. Yes, the environment is bootstrapped, let me try and share all that information here.

Comment: For debugging, try adding a `cdk ls` to the synth action to see which stacks it's synthesizing.

Comment: Hi @gshpychka, sorry I'm new to this, I've added the code to the questions.
As per your suggestion, I've added 'cdk ls' to synth step and here's what it gave back:
`Running command npx cdk ls
npx: installed 199 in 4.007s
XxxJavaxxxStack`

Comment: Hi @gshpychka, I believe this is whats happening, the code is synthesising `XxxJavaxxxStack` but its trying to deploy `xxxPipelinexxxStack `, is that why its failing? If so, how to get over this please?

Comment: please format your code in proper code blocks, it is very hard to understand the structure right now. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: What's in `xxxPipelineXXXStage`? It's supposed to have `xxxJavaxxxStack` in it, but you seem to be initiating that somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @kichik for help in formatting.
The class `xxxPipelineXXXStage` extends stage and just initiates the xxxJavaxxxStack class.
`new xxxJavaxxxStack(this, "xxxxStack")`.
Any help is much appreciated @kichik @gshpychka.

Comment: You should not initiate your stacks in anywhere but the stage. Try removing it from `xxxxPipelinexxxApp`. Also try adding `cdk ls` to the CodeBuild project for the update pipeline step as @TJ-AWS suggested.

Comment: Let me try that, thanks @kichik.
I have one query however, the pipeline is failing even before it reached the deploy 'stage', its failing in selfmutate. Even if I remove it from pipelineapp class, will this selfmutate stage pass?

Comment: Your synth step is synthesizing the wrong templates. It's not synthesizing the pipeline template which is why the self mutate step fails. It's unclear why without minimal code reproduction. All we can do is guess.

Comment: After fixing the error above, redeploy (just the pipeline) with `cdk deploy PipelineStack`. Don't forget to remove the app stack in CloudFormation after removing it from the CDK code as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks @gshpychka, I'll do that and let you guys know. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks @kichik. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi @kichik, thanks a lot for all the help, I could understand the issue when gshpychka suggested adding 'cdk ls' which made me realise I was providing the <git-repo> wrong in the above code, it was pointing to xxxJavaxxxStack repo instead of xxxPipelinexxxStack repo. I've updated it now and its working.

Comment: Hi @gshpychka, thanks a lot for all the help, I could understand the issue with your help and its now working,

Comment: @TJ-AWS you should post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed as I used 2 different github repositories (repos). The first was `xxxJava` repo which had `xxxJavaxxxApp.java` and `xxxJavaxxxStack.java` classes along with other necessary files.
The second was a `xxxPipeline` repo which had `xxxPipelinexxxApp.java` and `xxxPipelinexxxStack.java` along with other necessary files.

Initially I was wrong in using `xxxJava` repo in **git-repo** for the code `<git-owner>/<git-repo>` which was **synthesising** the `xxxJavaxxxStack` and the pipeline was expecting `xxxPipelinexxxStack` to deploy it.
The solution was to add the pipeline repo while creating the connection to github.
since the stage was unable to find this stack, it was failing at the 'selfmutate' stage.

I struck gold when @gshpychka mentioned to add the `cdk ls` to my **synth** step to see what stack was getting synth-ed!
`commands(Arrays.asList("mvn clean install", "npx cdk synth", "npx cdk ls"))`

The point to remember - till the 'selfmutate' stage, the pipeline related changes get deployed, and any stages added after, the actual stack/AWS-services get deployed.